# handle swipe react JS

Tags: reactjs, swipe

How to handle left and right swipes in react js.
There is a div block in which I want to catch swipes.
I also wanted to determine how long the swipe was in pixels.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using hammerjs.
Here is an implementation :

```
var hammertime = Hammer(el);
hammertime.get('swipe').set({
    direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL
});
```

Comment: npm i hammerjs?

Comment: yes, but not that this library is not actively maintained and there are native solutions like scroll snap that allow you to achieve the same result without even using javascript

Comment: Yep, however I just take a look, and there is also react wrapper for hammerjs available on NPM (ie: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hammerjs)

Comment: I think react-hammerjs suits me better